# Material UI v0.15.0-beta.1 material-ui-codemod is not in NPM directory

Tags: material-ui

I'm updating from MUI v0.15.0-alpha.2 to v0.15.0-beta.1, and the README says there's a codemod for automatically updating all of the `import` statements. However, if I follow the directions here:

https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui-codemod/README.md

...and run `nam install material-ui-codemod` as instructed, I get the following error back from NPM:

'material-ui-codemod is not in the npm registry.'

Is there something I'm missing here, or is this really busted? Manually updating all of the MUI calls in our code would be really time-consuming, especially since it's not obvious what all the new `import` statements should be, and the beta.1 documentation does not appear to be out anywhere.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Having the same issue. Seems like they haven't registered this package with NPM. Reverted to 0.15.0-alpha.2 for now until its sorted.

Comment: Yeah, I'm just going through by hand now. The beta.1 docs are up. For the record, "Left Nav" has become "Drawer".

Comment: ...and then "selectable-enhance" is now `MakeSelectable`, and is within the `List` group, like this:

`import {List, ListItem, MakeSelectable} from 'material-ui/List';`

Answer (score 0):

Indeed it's not published on npm. But you can use it easily.
Copy this [file](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui-codemod/transforms/v0.15.0/import-path.js) to your project and follow the other steps from the docs (skipping the material-ui-codemod installing of course) and pointing the command to the new path.

Comment: import-path.js is still work in progress., as of today. Many imports are not getting updated properly.

Comment: I agree., just mentioning here., if some one is working on a huge project, it may be hard for them.